# C - Comparing arrays (sets) of integers - hashing or tries

Tags: c, arrays, hash, trie

I have a program that will be generating arrays of integers. I need to be able to efficiently check if a newly generated array has already been generated before. Here is what I know about the nature of these arrays:

- The integers would be between 0 and around 200,000
- The number of integers in a single array is arbitrary, but I suppose less than 200
- The ordering of the integers does not matter. Repetitions do not matter as well. So the array `5 5 7 19` should be regarded the same as `7 5 19 7 7` (they should be viewed as sets rather than arrays, basically)
- The number of generated arrays would be in the hundreds of thousands, so I need this to be efficient

I was thinking about using some trie data structure. For this, I would need to sort the array, then traverse the trie, ignoring consecutive duplicates.

However, tries are usually used for character stuff, where you know that all nodes will have for example 26 children, thus the children can be easily stored and looked up in a 26-element array. In my case though, I have integers that could go up to 200,000 - so obviously an array of children is infeasible. Is it possible to create an efficient trie for such integers?

My other idea is to use a hash table. This will require a hashing function that does not care about the ordering of the elements and is idempotent with respect to duplicates. Does such a hashing function exist? If not, I would again need to sort the array and feed it to a regular hash function. And of course deal with collisions.

Lastly, which one of these would be more efficient? Or maybe some other data structure I didn't think of?

Comment: are you worried about memory or speed?

Comment: @nightshade memory is not a big concern, as long as it fits into a 32-bit process, but speed is essential, since the amount of data is quite large.

Comment: does it have to be in C or can you use C++?

Comment: @nightshade the project is in C, so I prefer that, but I suppose I could write a wrapping around the C++ code.

Comment: c++ has a set data structure... you can use arrays of sets or something like that

Comment: @Godkiller: How about sorting each array of integers within itself (thereby ignoring order), then adding the arrays to a B-tree? The comparison function for the B-tree would then implement a comparison function for 2 *arrays* of integers, and all should be well.

Comment: @nightshade well yeah, but `set` would make the comparisons element by element, destroying any notion of performance. C++ also has a `hash_set` data structure, which compares quickly, but requires me to provide a hashing function, which is the second part of my question... so that doesn't really help me.

Comment: @Baldrick the comparisons would still take O(n1+n2) each, where n1 and n2 are the lengths of the arrays. And each array will have to be sorted. Do you think this will be quick enough?

Comment: I think so, in your case. And in an overwhelming number of cases, the comparison will stop a very short way into the arrays when they differ. I've implemented something similar in the past - if you're only talking a few hundred thousand arrays of a few hundred ints, performance will be fine this way. I'll try to do a performance test, and post the code later today.

Comment: @Baldrick so the B-tree searches and insertions are `O(logn * O(_comparison_))`, where `n` is the number of elements, correct? Comparison in my case is roughly `O(m)`, where `m` is the length of the array. So all in all I have a sort + B-tree = `mlogm + mlogn`.

On the other hand, if I sort each array, hash it through a simple hash function and use a hash map with `logn` complexity, the whole operation would be mlogm + logn. And easier to implement than a freaking B-tree. Unless I'm missing something, of course.

Comment: @Godkiller: Given the data you're working on is pretty small, rather than analysing algorithmic complexity, my approach would be: qsort the arrays, grab some reasonable looking B-tree implementation from the net, bash it together and see if it's fast enough. You could do just the same with your hash map approach too - whatever you'd find easiest to implement / copy! I would consider more complex alternatives only if this approach isn't fast enough (which it very likely will be).

Comment: with the numbers you're putting up, I have to assume have some semblance of bias source.  You've significantly higher odds of winning *multiple* nationwide lotteries simultaneously. assuming your sample pull is 100 digits (half your max) from a pool of 200,000 values, the probability even with removing duplicate values of a duplicate sequence set is minuscule. Baring a blind squirrel helping a monkey write shakespeare with a nut, duplicates will be *rare*. and fairly quickly (7+unique values per sequence will take *millions*  of samples for a normal-based collision).

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, the distribution is far from random. Chances for duplicates are fairly high inside the arrays and mediocre for the whole arrays themselves. I'm currently implementing a hash based on lookup3, backed by a B-Tree. We'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to hash the lists. The arrays should ideally be kept sorted. You could create a standard accumulating hashing function that would skip over duplicates in a list if it is already sorted. I feel like a better solution would be to keep track of duplicates separately. If you could control the data structure going into the check and had to keep track of quantity of the list, you could store the list as a mapping of the integer to its quantity. Depending on the size of the list it may be faster to do this with a simple sorted array where each element is a struct with the integer and quantity as it will be faster to iterate through than something like a binary search tree (such as set). This increases the time to construct the list a bit but could be a good option if the check is more concerning. Arranging things in this manor allows you to find if a list is unique in time linear to the number of unique elements of the integer array.